# It is possible to use auto-properties and have some logic in the set?

Tags: c#, accessor, automatic-properties

It is possible to use auto-properties and have some logic in the set?

```
    public bool IsAwesome 
    { 
        get;
        private set
        {
            ?? = value;
            onIsAwesomeChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

NO, then it's no more a `auto-property`. If you have the posted code and try compiling you will get compiler error saying you must declare body for `get` accessor.